# Error occurred during initialization of VM, Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: java, minecraft, ram

I tried to make a Minecraft Server, using the suggestions I've seen people telling others to use the Paper API. So I got all the files, and I allocated 512 MB of ram to it (using -Xmx512M), and it runs completely fine! But it bumps into the limit of RAM too much, so I  tried to push it to 3 GB (using -Xmx3G). (A bit excessive, for what I'm using it for, but it'll help me sleep at night, knowing I have a server that's not running into issues) but then I run into the problem where Java simply does not want to start.

I experimented a bit, found that anything higher than 1.5G and Java starts having problems. [Could not reserve enough space for 3145728KB object heap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF1jb.png)
.

So I went looking around, and found people saying "Add an Environment Variable to the System Variables with _JAVA_OPTIONS and -Xmx3G" and whatever, and it appears to not change anything for me. Java still doesn't want to start. Does anyone know how this is? I can't seem to update my Java to any higher version, assuming mine was outdated. So it can't be an update, and not everyone runs into this issue because a server manager once told me their server ran with 10GB of ram.

I'd ask them, but I've lost contact, so I'm asking here instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

Make sure you're running 64 Bit Java. Otherwise, go to the link above and get the Windows 64-Bit Offline download. then run that. Immediately fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You may be using a 32-bit Java installation. Check which Java is being executed and install/use the 64-bit version.